# Use of Iterator in java

Tags: java, iterator

I have a object type list like

```
List<Object> getRecords = records.getAllRecords();
ArrayList<String> recordsDetail = new ArrayList<String>();
recordsDetail = this.getRecordsDetail(getRecords.get(3));
model.addAttribute("recordsDetail", getRecords.get(3));
```

But when I am writing the method like

```
ArrayList<String> getRecordsDetail(Object records) {

}
```

Now I don't know how I can Iterate over `records` as records has some values as vector.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

If I do the same thing in JSP using spring MVC its working fine like

```
<c:forEach var="sData" items="${recordsDetail}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0">
                    <c:forEach var="sValues" items="${sData}" varStatus="colNo">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${colNo.count> 5 and colNo.count<9}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${sValues}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                <tr>
                            </c:when>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
                <hr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

But I want to do this processing in spring MVC controller and display the final results in JSP. So I am not able to find the way how i can iterate `records` in controller class.

Comment: `records` is an object, not a list. Why would you want to iterate over it? Or did you mean `getRecords` instead?

Comment: In your method `ArrayList<String> getRecordsDetail(..)` -- you should return `List<String>` not `ArrayList<String>` unless there's some reason that it's important for the caller to *know* that it's actually an ArrayList. (unrelated to your question)  If it's not important to the caller, I'll even return `Collection<OfSomething>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

First, don't initialize a local variable then set it immediately to something.  Instead, just initialize to the desired value (note List type and not ArrayList type, that is a good practice or maybe just my preference).

```
List<String> recordsDetail = this.getRecordsDetail(getRecords.get(3));
```

Next, iterate over `records`

```
List<String> getRecordsDetail(Object records)
{
  if (records instanceof Vector)
  {
    Object blam;
    Iterator iterator;
    Vector recordVector = (Vector)records;

    iterator = recordVector.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
      blam = iterator.next();
      // do something with blam.
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know the type of the records elements, so I used `Object` if you know the type, then use that instead of Object.

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
ArrayList<String> getRecordsDetail(List<Object> records) {

}
```

If you can be more specific about the type of object returned by `records.getAllRecords()` you should use `List<the-object-type-returned-by-getAllRecords>` instead.